# How does context of reference determined

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces

I'm trying to understand the rule of the section 3.4.3.2/3 of N3797 c++14 final working draft:

> Given X::m (where X is a user-declared namespace), or given ::m (where
>   X is the global namespace), if S(X, m) is the empty set, the program
>   is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(X, m) has exactly one member, or if the
>   context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m) is
>   the required set of declarations of m. Otherwise if the use of m is
>   not one that allows a unique declaration to be chosen from S(X, m),
>   the program is ill-formed.

I've written the following code:

```
inline namespace A
{
    int i = 42;
};

namespace B 
{
    static const int i = 5;
};

using B::i;

int g= ::i //S(X, i)={using B::i, A::i}

int main() { }
```

As said in the quote cited above we have:

> [...]if S(X, m) is the empty set[...]

S(X,m) is not empty, further:

> Otherwise, if S(X, m) has exactly one member

is not true, further:

> or if the context of the reference is a using-declaration

I don't understand how does that constraint checked for my example. I would like to understand how does context of reference determined depends on the using of that reference?

Comment: "section 3.4.3.2/3" of which document? I have a guess, but it costs some time to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is all simple though is written in the confusing manner. Either a name is a member of the namespace or its inlined namespaces or the name is a name introduced by a using directive of some other namespace. If such a name is exactly one name then it will be used.

In your code example S( global, i ) has two members that is one is defined in the inlined namespace A and the other is introduced by using declaration. So there is an ambiguity.

So the order of considering namespaces is the following.
At first there is considered the namespace itself and its inlining namespaces. If the name is exactly one then it is used.

Otherewise the compiler considers using directives. If again the name is exactly one it is used.

In all other cases the program is ill-formed.

You have to consider the previous paragraph of the Standard

> 2 For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S0(X,m) be the set of all
>   declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). **If
>   S0(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S0(X,m);** otherwise, S(X,m) is the
>   union of S(Ni,m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives
>   in X and its inline namespace set.

EDIT: I am sorry. I mixed using declarations and using directive. In your example there is a using declarations. So the name is ambiguous. Id instead of

```
using B::i;
```

there would be

```
using namespace B;
```

then there would not be ambiguity.

You should compare two examples

The first one is exactly that you showed.

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace A
{
    int i = 42;
};

namespace B 
{
    static const int i = 5;
};

using B::i;

int g= ::i;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << g << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code will not be compiled because S( global, i ) contains two members.

And the other example

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace A
{
    int i = 42;
};

namespace B 
{
    static const int i = 5;
};

using namespace B;

int g= ::i;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << g << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code will be compiled because the name i in namespace B will not be considered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't agree with the following: `Using declarations are not considered if the set is not empty.`. The 3.4.3.2/2 said that using-**directive** is not considered if the S(X, m) is not empty.

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv I updated my post. I mixed up using declarations with using directive. I am sorry.

Comment: I understood how does S(X, m) determined. But I would like to clarify what exactly the rule `or if the context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m) is the required set of declarations of m.` mean. And how does context of reference determined. Can you improve your answer?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv There is no special term "context of reference". In this phrase it means simply that refered name is introduced in the namespace by using declaration. That is whether the namepsace declaraes the name itself of the name was introduced by using declaration.

Comment: I think that the constraint or `if the context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3)` is unnecessary. It is because using-declaration is also declaration and I think that it is too much. Am I right?